# Pandas select columns with boolean date condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to use a boolean index to select columns from a pandas dataframe with a datetime index as the column header:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 6), index=list('ABCD'), columns=dates)
```

returns:

```
   2013-01-01  2013-01-02  2013-01-03  2013-01-04  2013-01-05  2013-01-06
A    0.173096    0.344348    1.059990   -1.246944    1.624399   -0.276052
B    0.277148    0.965226   -1.301612   -1.264500   -0.124489    1.704485
C   -0.375106    0.103812    0.939749   -2.826329   -0.275420    0.664325
D    0.039756    0.631373    0.643565   -1.516543   -0.654626   -1.544038
```

I'd like to return only the first three columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might do

```
>>> df.loc[:, df.columns <= datetime(2013, 1, 3)]
   2013-01-01  2013-01-02  2013-01-03
A    1.058112    0.883429   -1.939846
B    0.753125    1.664276   -0.619355
C    0.014437    1.125824   -1.421609
D    1.879229    1.594623   -1.499875
```

You can do vectorized comparisons on the column index directly without using the `map`/`lambda` combination.

Comment: you can do this, less typing! ``df.loc[:, :'20130103']``

Comment: @Jeff: that actually feels a little too slick to me, somehow.. not sure how comfortable I am with some of the implicit datetime indexing rules.

Answer (score 1):

I had a nice long chat with the [duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and finally realised it was as simple as this:

```
print df.loc[:, :datetime(2013, 1, 3, 0, 0)]
```

I love Pandas.

EDIT:

Well, in fact that wasn't exactly what I wanted, because it relies on the 'query' date being present in the column headers. This is actually what I needed:

```
print df.loc[:, df.columns.map(lambda col: col < datetime(2013, 1, 3, 0, 0))]
```